# Print without Printer selection dialog

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, printing, report

I want to print my crystal report directly, without printer selection popup.
How can I do this ?

```
myReportDocument.SetDataSource(saveDataSet);
//Print
crystalReportViewer1.ShowRefreshButton = false;
crystalReportViewer1.ShowCloseButton = false;
crystalReportViewer1.ShowGroupTreeButton = false;
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myReportDocument;
crystalReportViewer1.PrintReport();
```

I'm using the default (and only) printer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myReportDocument.PrintOptions.PrinterName = "PRINTER_NAME";
myReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(copies, collate, startPage, endPage);
```